# AngularJs $broadcast() method pass object by value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, broadcast

I have a controller, which performs `$broadcast()` after retrieving data (as an object) from WebApi through my Angular custom service. Into the `$broadcast()` method it passes variable from its scope.

On the other side I have my custom directive with isolated scope, which listens to controller's broadcast and adds passed data to its own scope.

And when I change data in my directive's scope, they don't change in the controller's scope.

Actually, for me it's what I need.

**But**, if `$broadcast()` passes COPY OF REFERENCE to controller's scope object, **why directive doesn't see it object**?

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28119827/angular-broadcast-and-emit-send-message-objects-by-value-or-reference)

But its answer commits that reference is passed.

Here is my (TypeScript) code:

```
export class FoodSetController {
//variable that will reference to scope;
private _scope: any;
...
//constructor
static $inject = ["$scope", ...];
constructor($scope: any, ...) {
...
//initialize reference to scope
this._scope = $scope;
...
//initialize scope data be passed by &broadcast()
this._scope.foodSet = null;
...
}
...
//method that broadcasts scope data after it's retrieving from API
bindFoodSet(data): void {
...
this._scope.foodSet = data;//new Object()
...
this._scope.$broadcast("foodSetLoaded", this._scope.foodSet);
}
```

My custom directive (is created by factory):

```
export class FoodDiagramm implements ng.IDirective {
//scope property from ng.IDirective
public scope: boolean | Object;
...
//constructor
constructor() {
...
//create an isolated scope
this.scope = {};
...
}
//link method
public link($scope): void {
...
//add listener to isolated scope (HERE IS GOTCHA)
($scope as ng.IScope).$on("foodSetLoaded", (e: ng.IAngularEvent, foodSet: any): any => {
...
//?PASSED BY VALUE, BECAUSE DATA IN CONTROLLER'S SCOPE HADN'T BEEN CHANGED
foodSet = "zzz";
$scope.foodSet = foodSet;
});
...
}
```

Comment: you are changing the reference itself but not the object where the reference point to.

Comment: do you mean that I created new variable "zzz" and assigned it's address to "foodSet" ? And if I don't do [foodSet = "zzz";] but only [$scope.foodSet = foodSet;], I actually create new object $scope.foodSet and COPY to it content on whitch the "foodSet" points to ?

Comment: Yes, if you do `$scope.foodset = foodset` directly, $scope.foodset in the directive should point to the same object in the controller. What you do currently have no difference with `$scope.foodset = "zzz"`. You should test it to prove it, i might be wrong..

Comment: so it's interesting that as I wrote in the beginning, when I do `$scope.foodset = foodset` directly and AFTER IT change data in my directive's scope, they DON'T CHANGE in the controller's scope, whether I change them programmatically `$scope.foodSet = "zzz";` or thru directive's view in brouser